# I tried scheduling task on linux by crontab, but an error occur

Tags: linux, cron

```
SHELL= /bin/csh
MAILTO = myemail.com
PATH = /stoddiskpath


20 11 * * * script.csh
```

Above is my crontab script. However, I received an email with message:

```
tail: Command not found.
stoddiskpath/script.csh: Permission denied.
```

What does it mean by tail: command not found?

Comment: "linux tail: command not found" - please try a Google search with the same query and see if you can find some results.

Comment: `tail` does not live in the PATH /stoddiskpath, it usually lives in `/bin`. Maybe you should try `PATH=/stoddiskpath:$PATH` ? (Not sure about in crontab, I would do my path setting inside the script). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

log in to user account for which you are creating cron job.
Then `echo $PATH` and copy the contents to `PATH` variable of cron file.
And please make sure to give execute permissions to `script.csh` file and complete path of script file in cron command.